# Function that returns a generator fails, but when it is outside of the generator it works. Python and duckduckgo API

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I'm working on fast.ai's course and this is from the Kaggle Jupyter notebook for section 1. I'm using Python and the DuckDuckGo API to download images. This the [DDG API](https://pypi.org/project/duckduckgo-search/#3-images---image-search-by-duckduckgocom).

This creates a generator full of image URLs I can access.

```
with DDGS() as ddgs:
    keywords = 'dolphin'
    ddgs_dolphin_images_gen = ddgs.images(
      keywords,
      region="wt-wt",
      safesearch="moderate",
      type_image="photo",
    )
    
    dolphin = next(ddgs_dolphin_images_gen)
    print(dolphin)
    print(dolphin['image'])
```

This also creates a generator full of image URLs I can access.

```
with DDGS() as ddgs:
    keywords = 'dolphin'
    ddgs_images_gen = ddgs.images(
        keywords,
        region="wt-wt",
        safesearch="moderate",
        type_image="photo",
    )
    #must be indented to work
    #TODO ask SO
    dolphin = next(ddgs_images_gen)
    print(dolphin)
    print(dolphin['image'])
```

The above code works only if the part below the `with DDGS()` is indented more than the `with` statement. Which doesn't make any sense to me, since the lines below it are outside of the `with` block.

This is the function I wrote to run the image search. It returns a generator, but when I try to use it, I get an error message.

```
def search_ddg(search_terms):
    with DDGS() as ddgs: #what does as ddgs mean?
        keywords = search_terms,
        ddgs_images_gen = ddgs.images(
          keywords,
          region="wt-wt",
          safesearch="moderate",
          type_image="photo",
        )
    return ddgs_images_gen
```

Trying to use the generator:

```
dolphins = search_ddg('dolphin')
sharks = search_ddg('shark')
whales = search_ddg('whale')
print(type(dolphins)) #type generator

dolphin = next(dolphins) #ERROR HERE
shark = next(shark)
whale = next(whales)
print(dolphin)
print(dolphin['image'])
print(shark)
print(shark['image'])
print(whale)
print(whale['image'])
```

**This is the error message when I run the immediately above code:**

---

RuntimeError                              Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[70], line 7

```
      4 whales = search_ddg('whale')
      5 print(type(dolphins))
----> 7 dolphin = next(dolphins)
      8 shark = next(shark)
      9 whale = next(whales)
```

File /opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/duckduckgo_search/duckduckgo_search.py:407, in DDGS.images(self, keywords, region, safesearch, timelimit, size, color, type_image, layout, license_image)

```
    383 """DuckDuckGo images search. Query params: https://duckduckgo.com/params
    384 
    385 Args:
   (...)
    403 
    404 """
    405 assert keywords, "keywords is mandatory"
--> 407 vqd = self._get_vqd(keywords)
    408 assert vqd, "error in getting vqd"
    410 safesearch_base = {"on": 1, "moderate": 1, "off": -1}
```

File /opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/duckduckgo_search/duckduckgo_search.py:95, in DDGS._get_vqd(self, keywords)

```
     93 def _get_vqd(self, keywords: str) -> Optional[str]:
     94     """Get vqd value for a search query."""
---> 95     resp = self._get_url("POST", "https://duckduckgo.com class="ansi-yellow-bg" style="color:rgb(175,0,0)">", data={"q": keywords})
     96     if resp:
     97         for c1, c2 in (
     98             (b'vqd="', b'"'),
     99             (b"vqd=", b"&"),
    100             (b"vqd='", b"'"),
    101         ):
```

File /opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/duckduckgo_search/duckduckgo_search.py:89, in DDGS._get_url(self, method, url, **kwargs)

```
     87         logger.warning(f"_get_url() {url} {type(ex).__name__} {ex}")
     88         if i >= 2 or "418" in str(ex):
---> 89             raise ex
     90     sleep(3)
     91 return None
```

File /opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/duckduckgo_search/duckduckgo_search.py:78, in DDGS._get_url(self, method, url, **kwargs)

```
     76 for i in range(3):
     77     try:
    ---> 78         resp = self._client.request(
     79             method, url, follow_redirects=True, **kwargs
     80         )
     81         if self._is_500_in_url(str(resp.url)) or resp.status_code == 202:
     82             raise httpx._exceptions.HTTPError("")
```

File /opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/httpx/_client.py:814, in Client.request(self, method, url, content, data, files, json, params, headers, cookies, auth, follow_redirects, timeout, extensions)

```
    799     warnings.warn(message, DeprecationWarning)
    801 request = self.build_request(
    802     method=method,
    803     url=url,
   (...)
    812     extensions=extensions,
    813 )
    --> 814 return self.send(request, auth=auth, follow_redirects=follow_redirects)
```

File /opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/httpx/_client.py:890, in Client.send(self, request, stream, auth, follow_redirects)

```
    876 """
    877 Send a request.
    878 
   (...)
    887 [0]: /advanced/#request-instances
    888 """
    889 if self._state == ClientState.CLOSED:
    --> 890     raise RuntimeError("Cannot send a request, as the client has been closed.")
    892 self._state = ClientState.OPENED
    893 follow_redirects = (
    894     self.follow_redirects
    895     if isinstance(follow_redirects, UseClientDefault)
    896     else follow_redirects
    897 )
```

RuntimeError: Cannot send a request, as the client has been closed.

Comment: Apart from a different variable name, the first two code fragments are identical. Let's see the DDGS class. The comment "what does as ddgs mean?" is rather telling.

Comment: It's from `!pip install -Uqq  duckduckgo_search`  and `from duckduckgo_search import DDGS` The details of DDGS are explained in the API link at the top of my post

Comment: Do you have a question? What is it?

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to stop using the `with` block and remember to manually close it.

```
def search_ddg(search_terms):
    ddgs = DDGS()
    return ddgs.images(
        keywords = search_terms,
        region="wt-wt",
        safesearch="moderate",
        type_image="photo",
    )

dolphins = search_ddg('dolphin')
```

Comment: Not "the" solution but **one** solution, assuming that actually works. How do you manually close it later? And I think a far better solution would be to yield from inside the with-block, i.e., make `search_ddg` a generator.